# How compatible is MeshLab expected to be with the output of Blender?

Tags: blender, meshlab

How compatible is MeshLab v2020.05 expected to be with the output of Blender v2.82?

I'm running these programs under Win10 x64 Pro 1909.

Two recent attempts seem to indicate compatibility issues. In particular:

When I tried to load a model which had been exported by Blender v2.82 to .obj format, Meshlab v2020.05 complained that it didn't understand the .mtl file format.

This happened with the model of the Expanse Truman ship which is available at
https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/truman-class-dreadnough-command-v-the-expanse-391253a575d04be28c06140af59adfe7

When I tried to load a model which had been exported by Blender v2.82 to .dae format, MeshLab v2020.5 didn't complain, but the status line at the bottom of MeshLab's window claimed that the model had 0 vertices. The file was almost 300MB, so that certainly wasn't true.

This happened with the model of the Expanse Morrigan ship which is available at
https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/morrigan-class-patrol-destroyer-the-expanse-3a33b3d6bc574e6cbac5b921815870ce

Thanks for whatever help you can provide.

s.

Comment: Ideally there should not be any issue with opening an OBJ file imported from Blender in MeshLab. However, I had a look into the first model you have mentioned, and it looks like the OBJ file is not properly formatted. I had to make a couple of changes to be able to open it with MeshLab.Few of them being removing space from the .mtl filename (maybe MeshLab/Windows issue), replacing relative path for textures instead of hardcoded absolute paths in .mtl file (artist's fault or Blender, can't say), file extensions are wrong for many textures (*.jpg instead of *.jpeg) etc.

Comment: Can't say who is at fault for creating such messy OBJ/MTL. But you can follow the steps mentioned above to be able to open the file in MeshLab.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm confused by your response. For example, all of the on-disk surface texture images have a filetype of .jpg and all of the references to them in the .mtl file specify .jpg as the filetype.  I don't see any named .jpeg nor do I see any references to that filetype. In addition, spaces are common in file names these days, and the spaces in the name of the .mtl file match those the name of the .obj file and are as specified in the .obj file in its mtllib declaration. Are you saying that MeshLab doesn't understand a filetype of .jpg and can't handle spaces in filenames?

Comment: Apologies for causing confusion. When I downloaded the model from SketchFab in OBJ format, I had most on disk images with JPEG extension and a few with JPG extension. If you are not having that issue, then you can ignore that. MeshLab definitely support JPG as well as JPEG, as long as correct path is provided (which is not true in this case as image paths in MTL file are hardcoded absolute path from the system it was generated in, like "F:\\PROJECT slot\\TRUMAN CLASS\\Tetxures\\Engines\\"). And yes, MeshLab can't handle spaces in filenames, at least in MTL file name.